# Keep supporting old tickets after version-update

Tags: version-control, updates

Most of the basic ticketing platforms work like this: There is a website where users can buy a ticket for a specific event. After their information is stored in the database together with an unique ID or hash to identify the ticket, they receive an email with a QR-code. When entering the event, that QR-code (containing the unique ID/hash) gets scanned and the back-end checks if the ticket corresponding to that ID or hash exists, is valid, and is not yet used.

The security guards scanning the tickets at the entrance would have a dedicated but very basic app: The app scans the content of the QR-code on the ticket (the QR code only holds the unique ID/hash of the ticket), and sends that unique ID/hash to the back-end. If the checks on back-end conclude the ticket is valid the app shows a green screen to the guard, otherwise a red one. So the scanning-app is very 'dumb', simple, and basic.

**The question I have is: What if the logic of the back-end changes?**

Example: In 2017 we programmed a ticketing platform and decided to use MD5-hashes as unique identifier for all the tickets. So every ticket in the database has it's info saved (username, user-email, what event,...) together with it's own unique MD5-hash. The QR-code the owner of the ticket receives by mail also only contains that MD5-hash. This way we can link the physical ticket with the correct data in our database when using our dedicated scanning-app.

But now in 2021 we have decided that MD5 is not secure enough anymore and from now on we will be using SHA256-hashes to give the tickets unique IDs.
So from now on the column `hash_id` in the database contains SHA256 hashes and all the QR-codes we send by mail to the buyers contains the SHA256-hash matching their bought ticket.

And we change (pseudo-code):

```
if ($_POST['action_check_hash']) {
    if (md5_hash_is_valid_ticket($_POST['hash_on_ticket'])) {
        return GREEN_SCREEN;
    } else {
        return RED_SCREEN;
    }
}
```

to

```
if ($_POST['action_check_hash']) {
    if (sha256_hash_is_valid_ticket($_POST['hash_on_ticket'])) {
        return GREEN_SCREEN;
    } else {
        return RED_SCREEN;
    }
}
```

*Considering the given explanation we could also just compare the strings, nullifying the problem. But for the sake of this questions let's imagine we're using a hash-algorithm-dependent function to check if there exists a valid ticket with the given hash.*

The tickets do not have an expiration date.

So now user Foo who just bought his ticket yesterday comes to the entrance of the event and the security guard scans Foo's QR-code containing the SHA256-hash. `sha256_hash_is_valid_ticket($_POST['hash_on_ticket'])` returns a green screen and Foo can enter.

Now user Gux who bought his ticket in 2018 enters the entrance with his - actually valid ticket - containing a MD5-hash in it's QR-code (because in the old version of our platform we used MD5) but the security guard gets a red screen because `sha256_hash_is_valid_ticket($_POST['hash_on_ticket'])` returns a red screen. Obviously because the sha256-dependent function can't interpret the MD5-hash. So Gux does have a valid ticket, but can't enter the event because the back-end can't interpret his old ticket anymore.

How would we solve this? How do we make sure, when updating our back-end or platform, that already bought tickets do still work?

I was thinking something like this:
We put a specific version-number on our tickets so we can identify what version of the back-end we should use.

E.g:
The QR-code of the tickets in 2017 would contain:
`V1.0;098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6` (V1.0;MD5_HASH)
And the tickets bought in 2021 or later would contain
`V2.0;9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08` (V2.0;SHA256_HASH)

The back-end would look something like this:

```
if ($_POST['action_check_hash']) {
    valid = false;

    // Checking what version number the QR-code contains
    if ($_POST['version_on_ticket'] == "V1.0") {
        valid = md5_hash_is_valid_ticket($_POST['hash_on_ticket']);
    } 
    else if ($_POST['version_on_ticket'] == "V2.0") {
        valid = sha256_hash_is_valid_ticket($_POST['hash_on_ticket']);
    } else {
        valid = false;
    }

    if (valid) {
        return GREEN_SCREEN;
    }

    return RED_SCREEN;
}
```

Each update we make sure that the hash in the QR-code is prepended with a new version-number. In the back-end we then know what algorithm or logic to use by checking the version-number. Is this a good way to solve it?

A few solutions I came up with:

- The one explained above; Defining a version-number on the ticket which the scanner-apps sends to the back-end together with the hash. Back-end uses that version-number to interpret the data correctly.
- We save the timestamp of when a ticket was bought in the database. Then we'd use a separate table containing a version-number and the timestamp of when the update was pushed. The same principle as the previous solution but without exposing the version-number to the client.
- We give each ticket a unique URL so we can update the tickets of our users on-the-go (good for digital solutions, but what if the user prints his ticket?)
- We notify all of our users that our platform is updated and their previous tickets are not valid anymore, and mail them their tickets containing the new QR-code (for free). This will cause a lot of issues and will be expensive for customer support.

**TL;DR:**
How to keep old tickets using a format/logic not supported by the newest version of our back-end working. And how to let the back-end know it needs to switch to the old logic to interpret the incoming data correctly?

I am really looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using a version number for this is a good idea.  In general, you should assume that every format of data (tokens, identifiers, etc.) you emit to users will change and include a version number.  Then, when (not if) you need to make a change, you can just bump the version number.  This change can be the hash algorithm, the data you need to parse out of the identifier, or any other data format change you need to make.

The way I personally like to do this is to use a BER-encoded integer for this and just prepend it to the data, encoding it with hex or base64 or whatever you're using.  This is an encoding such that the lower seven bits of each byte represent the data, and the top bit is 1 if the integer continues to the next byte and 0 if this is the last byte.  This is variable-length, but it optimizes for smaller values (which are usually more frequent) and is easy to parse.  Of course, you can pick any sensible scheme you like.

Note that if you had picked a version number up front, you could simply have stored the identifier in the database with the version number prepended to it and then you wouldn't need an additional field specifying the type.  Of course, hindsight is always 20/20.